# how to refresh files/image gallery after delete with xmlhttp/ajax without reloading whole page?

Tags: php, ajax, image, gallery, xmlhttprequest

sorry for the lengthy question. i'll try to explain.

i have created a list of images that are visible when you hover over an element (using css)
each image is also a radio button to be chosen and used as part of a form.
All the images are basically all the images in a certain directory that you can also upload to.

I've managed to add a 'delete' button next to each image which will trigger a function that calls a php script to delete that particular image without reloading page. using xmlhttp.which works fine.

But the list of images doesn't refresh itself. As in the image i just deleted is still visible when i hover over the element until i refresh the page then it refreshes the list.

obviously i don't want to refresh the page, that was the whole point of using ajax. so any ideas what i can do? code is below:

```js
<script>
function deleteImage(){
 var answer =  confirm('Are you SURE you wish to delete this?')
 if (answer) {
   var image = document.getElementById('filepath').value;
   var xmlhttp;
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     else
     {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
     document.getElementById("uploadmsg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
    }
  xmlhttp.open("POST","delete.php",true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send("image="+image);
}
}
```

then the php/html to call it all.

```php
<?php
  $dir = "../images/";      
  $dh = opendir( $dir );
  while( $filename = readdir( $dh ) ) {
       $filepath = $dir.$filename;
       $gallery[] = $filepath;
       $list[] = $filename;           
  }
  sort( $gallery );
    sort( $list);
  $num_pics = count($gallery);
?>

<div id='chooseimg'  ><input type="text" value="Choose Image"><span><ul>        
<?php

$a = 2;
while($num_pics > $a)
{
    ?> 
    <li>
<input type='radio' name='image' value='<?php echo $list[$a]; ?>'>
<?php echo $list[$a]; ?> 
<div id='imglist'><img src='<?php echo$gallery[$a]; ?>' /></div>
<button type='button' onclick="deleteImage()">Delete</button> 
<input type="hidden" id="filepath" value="<?php print $gallery[$a]; ?>"/> </li>
    <?php
    $a ++;  }   
        ?>
</ul></span></div>
<div id="uploadmsg"> </div>
```

the file `delete.php` contains:

```php
<?php 
$image = $_POST['image'];
if (!empty($image)){
unlink($image);
echo "<b>Image deleted<b>";
}
?>
```

and the css to make the hover over thing work is basically a `span` inside a div `#chooseimage` that is set to `left:99999px;` but when `hover` over `chooseimg` it moves to `left:0px;`
i don't think anyone needs any more info on that but let me know if you do.

as a side note i'm not sure if this actualy ajax? maybe someone can clarify for me.

if you could help i'd be very grateful. i've googled for hours but can't find anything.

Comment: Well, you have to return something from your ajax call, so some javascript code, that will remove the deleted image from the page.

Comment: You should probably rethink your whole code, what you are doing is very risky. You are giving every one the possibility to delete all your files in the directory including all PHP files and so on.

Comment: how does someone have the posibility to delete everything? there is no user input except clicking a button. and the data is posted so no1 sees it???

Comment: djot.... thanx for your response... i don't know how to return something from my ajax call to remove the deleted image... hence the question. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so for anyone who has the same problem i figured it out.

the code to display all the images along with their radio and delete buttons are stored in a separate `php` file:

```
<?php
  $dir = "../images/";      
  $dh = opendir( $dir );
  while( $filename = readdir( $dh ) ) {

       $filepath = $dir.$filename;
       $gallery[] = $filepath;
       $list[] = $filename;           
  }
  sort( $gallery );
  sort( $list);
  $num_pics = count($gallery);
?>

<div id="choose"><div id="echo">
<div style="background-color: #F04D8E; color: #ffffff;">Choose Image</div></div> 
<span><ul>  

<?php
$a = 3;
while($num_pics > $a)
{
$image = $gallery[$a];
    ?> 

    <li>

//the radio button triggers an event which then showsthe image selected

<input id="radio" type='radio' name='image' onchange="thumb('<?php echo $image; ?>')" 
value='<?php echo $list[$a]; ?>'><?php echo $list[$a]; ?> 
<div id='gallery'>

// the delete button sends the images 'id' in its parameter
<button style="float:right;" type='button' 
onclick="deleteImage('<?php echo $image; ?>', '<?php echo $list[$a]; ?>'    )">    
Delete</button>
    <img src='<?php echo $image; ?>' /></div>
      </li>
    <?php

    $a ++;
 }                      
?>
</ul></span></div><br>
```

in the main page i call this script into a `div` straight away and also refresh it after the `deleteImage` function has been requested:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

window.onload = function(){
$('#result').load('show.php');
}

function deleteImage(id, name){
var answer =  confirm('Are you SURE you wish to delete ' + name + ' ?') 
if (answer) {
$.post("delete.php", { image: id })
.done(function(){
$('#uploadmsg').html("<b>" + name + " deleted </b>");
$('#result').ready(function(){
$('#result').load('show.php');

});
});
}}

function thumb(image){

$('#echo').html("<img src='"+image+"'>");

}
```

then all i need in the page is a `div` with `id` as `result`

oh and the `delete.php` page is still:

```
<?php 
$image = $_POST['image'];
if (!empty($image)){
unlink($image);
}
?>
```

someone said this is dangerous? but i can't see why.

and questions feel free to ask

thanx